# Escape apostrophe passed from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

in ASPX, I call a JS function when clicking on a button, passing in a variable from code behind, something like this:

```
... onclick="SelectEmpl('<%=employer.Name%>', '<%=employer.Surname%>', '<%=employer.Company%>')"
```

The problem is, that all parameters passed into the SelectEmpl function are strings and can contain the apostrophe character. In case this happens, the JS apostrophes are paired prematurely and evaluation fails.

I know I need to escape the apostrophes in the strings somehow but I'm not sure how when they are passed from CB.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function to escape the apostrophes then call it around each one. Something like:

```
Shared Function RemoveQuotes(ByVal input As String) As String
  Return Replace(input, "'", "\'")
End Function
```

Then:

```
... onclick="SelectEmpl('<%=RemoveQuotes(employer.Name)%>', '<%=RemoveQuotes(employer.Surname)%>', '<%=RemoveQuotes(employer.Company)%>')"
```

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there would be a more elegant solution but this fills its purpose. :)